# Is Slick Missing the Database Class?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I cannot find Slick's Database class.  It is referenced in all their guides.

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/gettingstarted.html

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {
  implicit session =>
  // <- write queries here
}
```

Seems to be missing from the API docs as well.

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Database` is actually something you import from the appropriate driver class.
In the guides, they start with this:

```
// Use H2Driver to connect to an H2 database
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
```

`H2Driver` is a `JdbcDriver`, which defines a whole lot of types. To simplify the import process, `JdbcDriver` defines a `SimpleQL` trait (of which `H2Driver.simple` is an instance). In that trait, you'll find `val Database`, which is actually a `DatabaseFactory`.

link: [SimpleQL in the docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile$SimpleQL)

Comment: I missed the 'simple' on the import so it never showed up.  Thanks